# Stored procedure delete rows by current day

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I need your help. I have a table as shown here:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07-12-22 | Simone | Jackson |
| 07-12-22 | Tyler | Connor |
| 07-19-22 | Brad | Barret |
| 07-19-22 | John | Bowiw |

I'm working on this stored procedure and it should delete the rows with the current day that was load it, in this case the rows with the date `07-12-22`, because these rows were uploaded today `07-19-22`, I'm not sure I'm right. Any help?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRowsbyCurrentDate()
    DECLARE @CurrentDay date = GETDATE()
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Customer.ClientFact
    WHERE Date = to_date(@CurrentDay,'YYYYMMDD')
END;
```

Comment: "delete the rows (...) with the date "07-12-22", because this rows was uploaded today 07-19-22". Very confusing and contradictory. What dbms do you use? What is the problem with your current code? Also, dates that are presented like that suggests they are strings, not dates. Please show your table structure

Comment: I would suggest working on your SELECT statement first. Once the SELECT statement returns the data you'd like to delete, you can convert that statement to DELETE. Are you using SSMS?  What is the table name, the name of the column that stores the upload date?